# Max key size limit in mongo db installation on CentOs

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongo db from rpm package as guided by site:

"https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/"

Now mongodb is working successfully. But now i am suffering the problem with key size limit. When i am adding more data to key field then mongo gives below error:

> "MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: WiredTigerIndex::insert:
>   key too large to index, failing".

I have searched this error on google and found that "Mongo has static key size limit 1KB". But i have found that many users has requested that key size should be removed and looks like they have removed as per below URL:

"https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/4c2e46a3e0873cea3564f02c23a6283078970ee9"

"https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36278"

So now problem is that

> "Key size limit is still in effect in latest version 4.0".

I have searched on internet to change this size manually in code but did't found any files to change for linux installation tar package. Looks like tar file consist of driver (non-editable files).

How can i overcome this error? I need to add large data in key field (Its requirement).

Note: I have asked same question at "https://superuser.com/questions/1424951/max-key-size-limit-in-mongo-db-installation-on-centos"

Comment: Sounds pretty much like there are values used as keys. Which is usually a sign of bad data models. You can only change that, since obviously you can not use the keys. Show us the data model, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: [As per documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#indexes), keys are still limited to 1k bytes.